# ssh server connect to host xxx port 22: Connection timed out on amazon linux 2

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, terraform

I am trying to connect to my ec2 webserver via shh from my ip address but getting connection timeout. below is my code

```
// Create security group for ec2 webserver
resource "aws_security_group" "web_sg" {
  name   = "web_sg"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress {
    description = "Allow SSH from my IP"
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["${var.my_ip}/32"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Allow all traffic from HTTP"
    from_port   = 80
    to_port     = 80
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  ingress {
    description = "Allow all traffic from HTTPS"
    from_port   = 443
    to_port     = 443
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    description = "Allow all outbound traffic"
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 0
    protocol    = "-1"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

}

// Create security group for db instance
resource "aws_security_group" "db_sg" {
  name   = "db_sg"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id

  ingress {
    description     = "Allow only MySQL traffic from web_sg "
    from_port       = 3306
    to_port         = 3306
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = [aws_security_group.web_sg.id]
  }

}
```

I have checked my interget gateway and route table and both seem to be ok.
what can i do to solve this

Comment: Have you configured any network access lists? Does your EC2 instance have a public IP address?

Comment: @mark, my network access list both inbound and outbound allow all traffic. yes,, my EC2 have a public Ip address but not an Elastic IP

Comment: Is the `my_ip` value a private IP or a public IP?

Answer (score 0):

From the provided security group Terraform configuration, it seems that you have restricted port 22 (SSH management) to a single IP address (/32). If this IP address belongs to your home, then you should be able to access your EC2 instance via a site-to-site VPN or the instance's public IP address.

Another option to consider instead of opening SSH up in your security group is [AWS Systems Manager Session Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/session-manager.html), which allows you to log in to your Linux server using the AWS console or AWS CLI without having to open port 22 to the internet. If you go this route, you could also use [AWS Patch Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-patch.html) to manage your OS patches.

Comment: the IP address is my home IP and i tried accessing the EC2 instance via its public IP address but it doesn't connect. I tried running a similar configuration I had and ssh via my IP to the instance public IP, and it worked. I do want to understand why i can't connect to the public IP of this instance via ssh. I will checkout AWS Systems Manger Session Manager

Comment: Since you mentioned that this is a web server, are you able to successfully connect to ports 80 and 443 without any issues? If so, this suggests that there may not be any networking issues. As a test, have you considered temporarily opening up SSH access to the internet by changing the "cidr_blocks" parameter from "${var.my_ip}/32" to "0.0.0.0/0"? This will allow you to verify whether the SSH connection issue is related to the security group configuration or something else.